# Как запускать основной цикл программы через телеграм бота?

Tags: python, telebot, while

Есть некий цикл while с использованием библиотеки ссхt, пытаюсь
запустить его через клавиатуру телеграм бота. Код примерно такой:

```
exchange = ccxt.ftx({
     'enableRateLimit': True,
     'apiKey': config.API_KEY,
     'secret': config.API_SECRET,
     'options': {
         'defaultType': 'future'
     },
     'headers': {
         'FTX-SUBACCOUNT': config.SUBACCOUNT
     }
 })

...........

 while True:
     if ....
    
 @bot.message_handler(content_types='text')
 def message_reply(message: types.Message)
     global exchange
     if message.text == "Старт":
        .......
        
 bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

`

Как запускать цикл while при нажатии кнопки старт? Если прописываю весь цикл после if message.text == "Старт": не работают все атрибуты ccxt, тоже самое если прописываю цикл отдельной функцией. Пробовал даже в бд сохранять нажатия кнопок) подскажите что я делаю не так

Comment: Зачем вам это ?

Comment: делаю управление ботом из телеги без захода на сервер

Comment: Я имею ввиду цикл вас зачем?

Comment: цикл это основная логика

Comment: то есть нажатие кнопки в телеграм запускает торгового бота

Comment: я немного хз что это у вас такое, но вы пробовали тупо запихнуть цикл в бота? Вдруг это то что вам нужно. Правда бот застынет после первого нажатия на кнопку старт

Comment: уже писал в вопросе что пробовал, и даже не застынет, только ни один запрос к бирже не пройдёт

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл выход разместив код телеграм в одном файле а цикл с основной логикой в другом, теперь запускаю один файл из другово через exec(open("file.py").read()) может не самый лучший вариант, но для меня работает